# Is there any method in iOS similar to Android's Search Suggestions?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, search

In android, the application can suggest words from sqlite that match the text entered so far by using ContentProvider. It is similar to Google's Autocomplete.

Is there any similar method in iOS? I'm new to iOS programming and trying to implement a dictionary in my app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a BOOL variable in your .m file.

```
BOOL isSearching;

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText  // this method called evry time when you edit text on search bar.
{
  isSearching = YES;
}
```